# Selenium Python: How to wait for div to appear, do stuff, then wait again and so on?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a website where I need to automate some actions. 
Every time a customer does a purchase, a div with an input and a submit button appears. On that div I need to enter a value and click submit. The div then closes until the next purchase appears in the same div.  I need to do the same actions, and so on. 
It's indefinite.

I already found some solutions that point to the direction:
[Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336)

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button"))).click()
```

But I can't provide a specific time to wait. I need a solution that keeps going in a loop indefinitely and progress all purchases throughout the day

Every solution that I find solves the problem that the website takes time to load. But I have a completely different problem underlying. I need to wait for a purchases to happen. So I can't set a specific time to wait. It could be indefinite.

What Selenium function could help me -in a best practice way- with my problem?

Comment: You can use a try except block within while loop to wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use try and except**

```py
while true:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button"))).click()
    except:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Yes, but I could happen that there isn't any purchase for 8 hours. Should I add then 28800s to wait? I was hoping for a more elegant way to solve this